# Solution to $x^3-y^2=6$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I have checked a lot of solutions where y is from 1 to 100,000 on Python, but none of them seem to work. Can you help me to find a solution to this equation? Is there even a solution?

Comment: are there any restrictions on our variables?  There are many trivial solutions

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell_curve

Comment: What if the equation is x^3+y^2=6 and they can be negative?

Comment: @bor presumably integer solutions are intended.

Comment: There is no solution in integers. See Theorem 2.4 of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf.

Comment: In the Mordell curve, can n be negative?

Comment: @user690234 Absolutely ok

Comment: okay, but is there solutions to x^3+y^2=6?